# Embed a PPT onto SharePoint

Tags: publishing-page

Can you embed an iFrame code from a PowerPoint slide show to a SharePoint page, but not allow anyone to have to ability to download or edit the document from the page?

Comment: Try using Page viewer web part.

Comment: The Page Viewer web part would not prevent visitors downloading the document. It just puts the embed code in an iFrame. The PowerPoint Online embed code allows downloading.